# windows 10 update Program not connecting with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-10, network-drive

Last night (5/9/2018) there was a windows update (Windows 10).

Today many programs (located on a network drive) which connects to a MS SQL 2005 is not able to connect to the SQL server.
**However, if I move the exe to the local drive (c:) it connects.**

Other computers (Windows 10 and Windows 8) which did not have an update seem to be working fine.

Any ideas what is the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has happened to a couple of computers in our office...but others seem to be working fine (Just to be clear).

Comment: Found a solution...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172067/sqlconnection-error-if-exe-is-executed-from-network-path   Thanks.

Comment: Found a solution. Thanks to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50172067/sqlconnection-error-if-exe-is-executed-from-network-path